# Bitbucket pipeline language templates not available on the list

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to incorporate pipeline into my project but I don't see my language on the list. My project is just HTML, CSS, and Javascript. Javascript is on the list but I think that choosing it will be overkill because I don't need node. Should I choose **Other** instead? Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Those templates are only there to provide a starting point - they are not fixed requirements. The "Other" template is probably a good place for you to start.